# How to identify authetication failure reason using omniauth-twitter gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, twitter-gem

I'm using `twitter + devise + omniauth + omniauth-twitter` to autheticate users via twitter api. From my site I reach, twitter login. I give my twitter credentials. After that I'm redirected to callback url. But the response says the authetication failed. Is there a way I can identify the reason for authetication failure.

If the authetication is successful, I'll have the information in `request.env['omniauth.auth']` . What about when the authetication fails? Is there any similar variable available?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `request.env['omniauth.error']`.

Answer (score 0):

Omniauth redirects to "/auth/failure" when the authentication fails and it passes a message parameter with the error. So if you catch that in your routes.rb, then you can log `params[:message]` in the corresponding controller action to figure out what happened.